# How does a tor node knows that the next hop is a node and not the final destination?

Tags: node

I was reading https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36571/why-can-a-tor-exit-node-decrypt-data-but-not-the-entry-node and it got me thinking: `How does a tor node knows that the next hop is a node and not the final destination?`.

In the normal `tcp/ip` packet you have `source address` and `destination address`. How can TOR packets know that they did not reached their destination and it's not only another hop on the chain? Does the packet has any type of `TCP options` like the `TCP/IP` packet does?

Comment: You are telling me that using TOR is the same as using a proxy?

Comment: Oh, I think I missunderstood your question with my first comment (now deleted). I think the nodes know at which position in the chain they are when the connection with the client is negotiated (the TOR client negotiates a connection with all three nodes individiually and likely tells them their assigned role)

Comment: @cremefraiche I did not have knowledge of such community. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks it is a clear duplicate, no doubt

Answer (score 0):

If an OR is an exit node, it will receive a RELAY cell that tell it to establish a tcp connection with a server. If it is not an exit node, it will receive an EXTEND cell that tells it to extend the tor circuit to another OR. See https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt for more.